# Replace values from another dataframe by IDs

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames::

```
as1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                  pID = c(21,22,23,24,25,26),
                  Values = c(435,33,45,NA, NA,12))
as2 <- data.frame(ID = c(4,5),
                  pid = c(24,25),
                  Values = c(544, 676))
```

I need to replace the NA values in as1 with those in as2 by matching ID and pID

I need to get the result data frame as:

```
  resultdf
    ID pID Values
    1  1  21    435
    2  2  22     33
    3  3  23     45
    4  4  24    544
    5  5  25    676
    6  6  26     12
```

I tried doing subset and then `na.omit()` and then `rbind`ing... but I'm losing the index.

Answer (score 15):

Here are two base R solutions.

First, using `match` in "ID" to select the elements of "Value" in as1 to fill in:

```
as1$Values[match(as2$ID, as1$ID)] <- as2$Values

as1
  ID pID Values
1  1  21    435
2  2  22     33
3  3  23     45
4  4  24    544
5  5  25    676
6  6  26     12
```

This only works if ID is the true ID for both data sets (that is, pid is "irrelevant").  Second, in the case that pid is also needed, you could use `merge` and then "collapse" the two values columns as follows:

```
df <- merge(as1, as2, by.x=c("ID", "pID"), by.y=c("ID", "pid"), all=TRUE)
```

This produces a four column data frame with two values columns. Collapse these into a single column with `ifelse`:

```
df <- cbind(df[c(1,2)], "Values"=with(df, ifelse(is.na(Values.y), Values.x, Values.y)))

df
  ID pID Values
1  1  21    435
2  2  22     33
3  3  23     45
4  4  24    544
5  5  25    676
6  6  26     12
```

Comment: I think this is a great answer because it allows you to insert the numbers in-place without cleaning up a dplyr `left_join()` where the data gets duplicated.  One thing I want to point out is that the order of parameters inside `match()` matters, so pay attention to that.

Answer (score 7):

Try with `dplyr` library. Firstly join both tables and then create new column with values instead `NA`'s:

```
library("dplyr")

as1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), pid = c(21,22,23,24,25,26),Values = c(435,33,45,NA, NA,12))
as2 <- data.frame(ID = c(4,5),pid = c(24,25), Values = c(544, 676))

left_join(as1, as2, by = c("ID", "pid")) %>% 
    mutate(Values = ifelse(is.na(Values.x), Values.y, Values.x)) %>% 
    select(ID, pid, Values)

# ID pid Values
# 1  1  21    435
# 2  2  22     33
# 3  3  23     45
# 4  4  24    544
# 5  5  25    676
# 6  6  26     12
```

Answer (score 7):

Following Marta's `dplyr` solution, we can use `coalesce` instead to combine the merged `Value.x` and `Value.y`:

```
library(dplyr)
res <- as1 %>% left_join(as2, by = c("ID", "pID"="pid")) %>%
               mutate(Values=coalesce(Values.x,Values.y)) %>%
               select(-Values.x,-Values.y)
##  ID pID Values
##1  1  21    435
##2  2  22     33
##3  3  23     45
##4  4  24    544
##5  5  25    676
##6  6  26     12
```

Note also the syntax used for the `by` parameter in `left_join`. Here, we join by `ID` and by `pID` for `as1` and `pid` for `as2`.

Answer (score 6):

Or another option is `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(as1)[as2, Values := i.Values , on =.(ID, pid)]
as1
#    ID pid Values
#1:  1  21    435
#2:  2  22     33
#3:  3  23     45
#4:  4  24    544
#5:  5  25    676
#6:  6  26     12
```