# How to replace variables for certain observations in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-analysis, data-cleaning

So I have a list of countries in my survey with their specific spellings. I have another dataframe which has a score for each country, but the name of some of the countries are spelled differently than those in my survey (e.g. it is "Republic of Korea" in my survey and "South Korea" in that dataframe). When I merge these two dataframes, the score for those countries turn NA since they don't match.

I decided to build a dataframe of rows with the two different spellings being the two variables: should go about it?

```
                           correct_names                    incorrect
1                 BOSNIA AND HERZEGOVINA           BOSNIA HERZEGOVINA
2  CONGO- THE DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF CONGO
3              IRAN- ISLAMIC REPUBLIC OF                         IRAN
4                     KOREA- REPUBLIC OF                  SOUTH KOREA
5                 LIBYAN ARAB JAMAHIRIYA                        LIBYA
6                               MALDIVES                         NONE
7                             MARTINIQUE                         NONE
8                                MAYOTTE                         NONE
9                   MOLDOVA- REPUBLIC OF                      MOLDOVA
10                    RUSSIAN FEDERATION                       RUSSIA
11                  SYRIAN ARAB REPUBLIC                        SYRIA
12             TAIWAN- PROVINCE OF CHINA                       TAIWAN
13          TANZANIA- UNITED REPUBLIC OF                     TANZANIA
14                  UNITED ARAB EMIRATES                         NONE
15                              VIET NAM                      VIETNAM
```

Now I want R to replace the "incorrect" names in the dataframe with my "correct" names. Anyone has any idea how I should go about it?

Comment: This seems most likely to be a duplicate of [Replace values from another dataframe by IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40177132/replace-values-from-another-dataframe-by-ids)

Comment: Not exactly what you are looking for, but perhaps easier is to use the `str_replace_all()` function from the `stringr` package.  You could create a named vector with the incorrect country name and its replacement value, e.g. `replace_vec <- c(incorrect_name1 = correct_name1, incorrect_name2 = correct_name2)`. You can subsequently pass this vector to the `str_replace_all()` function: `df$correct_name <- str_replace_all(df$incorrect_name, replace_vec)`

Comment: Using `str_replace` for whole value comparisons like that is quite risky if any of the incorrect names are substrings of each other.

Comment: you should be search for `fuzzy_join`.

Comment: `library(dplyr); df %>% left_join(TABLE_OF_CORRECTIONS, by = c("country" = "incorrect")) %>% mutate(country = coalesce(correct_names, country))`